# Create a new column in Pandas dataframe based on different conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, data-manipulation

This is a small part of my huge dataframe:

```
data = {'index':  ['001', '001', '002', '002', '003', '003', '003', '004', '004', '004', '004', '005'],
        'vehicle': ['none', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'none', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'bus', 'bus', 'bus', 'motorcycle'],
        'cas_class': ['pedestrian', 'driver', 'driver', 'passenger', 'pedestrian', 'driver', 'driver', 'driver', 'driver', 'passenger', 'passenger', 'driver']}

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['index', 'vehicle', 'cas_class']) 
df
```

output:

```
    index   vehicle     cas_class
0   001     none        pedestrian
1   001     car         driver
2   002     car         driver
3   002     car         passenger
4   003     none        pedestrian
5   003     car         driver
6   003     car         driver
7   004     car         driver
8   004     bus         driver
9   004     bus         passenger
10  004     bus         passenger
11  005     motorcycle  driver
```

1. What I want to do is to count how many vehicles were involved per each index (index is indicating the accident). What is the easiest and fastest way to count by condition?
   For example, I can count number of drivers per each accident, and that way I will know how many vehicles I had in each accident.

With this code I managed to do it:

```
n_of_veh = df[df["cas_class"]=='driver'].groupby(['index']).size().reset_index()\
           .rename(columns= {0: 'n_of_veh'})
df = df.merge(n_of_veh, on='index')
```

---

### This part is still something I am trying to figure out:

2. I also want to add another column named 'reference', where I can reference which casualty was in which vehicle or in the case of pedestrian, which vehicle hit the pedestrian.

Can someone help out? I am still learning pandas. :/

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
    index   vehicle     class        n_of_veh   reference
0   001     none        pedestrian   1          1  
1   001     car         driver       1          1
2   002     car         driver       1          1
3   002     car         passenger    1          1
4   003     none        pedestrian   2          1
5   003     car         driver       2          1
6   003     car         driver       2          2
7   004     car         driver       2          1 
8   004     bus         driver       2          2
9   004     bus         passenger    2          2
10  004     bus         passenger    2          2
11  005     motorcycle  driver       1          1
```

---

#### EDIT

Translation of [the original data](https://datos.madrid.es/egob/catalogo/300228-18-accidentes-trafico-detalle.csv):

```
# columns translation
df = df.rename({'FECHA': 'Date', 'RANGO HORARIO': 'Hour', 'DIA SEMANA': 'Day_of_Week', 'DISTRITO': 'District', 'LUGAR ACCIDENTE': 'Street_Address', 'Nº': 'Street_Number', 'Nº PARTE': 'Accident_Index', 'CPFA Granizo': 'WC_Hail', 'CPFA Hielo': 'WC_Ice', 'CPFA Lluvia': 'WC_Rainy', 'CPFA Niebla': 'WC_Foggy', 'CPFA Seco': 'WC_Dry', 'CPFA Nieve': 'WC_Snowy', 'CPSV Mojada': 'RC_Wet', 'CPSV Aceite': 'RC_Oil', 'CPSV Barro': 'RC_Mud', 'CPSV Grava Suelta': 'RC_Gravel_Loose', 'CPSV Hielo': 'RC_Ice', 'CPSV Seca Y Limpia': 'RC_Dry_and_Clean', '* Nº VICTIMAS': 'Number_of_Casualties', 'TIPO ACCIDENTE': 'Collision_Type', 'Tipo Vehiculo': 'Vehicle_Type', 'TIPO PERSONA': 'Casualty_Class', 'SEXO': 'Sex_of_Casualty', 'LESIVIDAD': 'Casualty_Severity', 'Tramo Edad': 'Age_Band_of_Casualty'}, axis=1)

# removing columns that are not needed
df = df.drop(columns= ['Date', 'Hour', 'Day_of_Week', 'District', 'Street_Address', 'Street_Number', 'WC_Hail', 'WC_Ice', 'WC_Rainy', 'WC_Foggy', 'WC_Dry', 'WC_Snowy', 'RC_Wet', 'RC_Oil', 'RC_Mud', 'RC_Gravel_Loose', 'RC_Ice', 'RC_Dry_and_Clean', 'Sex_of_Casualty', 'Age_Band_of_Casualty'])

# other translations
collision_dict = {'COLISION DOBLE': 'Double_Collision', 'ATROPELLO': 'Pedestrian_Hit', 'COLISION MULTIPLE': 'Multiple_Collision', 'CAIDA MOTOCICLETA': 'Motorcycle_Fall', 'CHOQUE CON OBJETO FIJO': 'Accident_with_a_Fixed_Object', 'CAIDA VIAJERO BUS': 'Bus_Passenger_Fall', 'CAIDA BICICLETA': 'Bicycle_Fall', 'CAIDA CICLOMOTOR': 'Moped_Fall', 'OTRAS CAUSAS': 'Other_Types', 'VUELCO': 'Ended_on_the_Roof', 'CAIDA VEHICULO 3 RUEDAS': '3-Wheel_Vehicle_Fall'}
vehtype_dict = {'TURISMO': 'OtherVehicles', 'NO ASIGNADO': 'Not_Assigned', 'MOTOCICLETA': 'Motorcycle', 'FURGONETA': 'GoodsVehicle', 'AUTOBUS-AUTOCAR': 'BusCoach', 'AUTO-TAXI': 'CarTaxi', 'BICICLETA': 'Bicycle', 'CICLOMOTOR': 'Motorcycle', 'CAMION': 'GoodsVehicle', 'VARIOS': 'OtherVehicles', 'AMBULANCIA': 'OtherVehicles', 'VEH.3 RUEDAS': 'OtherVehicles'}
cclass_dict = {'CONDUCTOR': 'Driver', 'VIAJERO': 'Passenger', 'TESTIGO': 'Witness', 'PEATON': 'Pedestrian'}
csev_dict = {'HL' : 'Slight', 'HG': 'Serious', 'MT': 'Fatal', 'NO ASIGNADA': 'Not_Assigned', 'IL': 'Not_Injured'}

df.replace({'Collision_Type': collision_dict}, regex=True, inplace=True)
df.replace({'Vehicle_Type': vehtype_dict}, regex=True, inplace=True)
df.replace({'Casualty_Class': cclass_dict}, regex=True, inplace=True)
df.replace({'Casualty_Severity': csev_dict}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT

This solution answers to the original dataset posted by the OP in a successive edit. The variable names will be picked by the original data, not the sample data at the beginning of the question.

---

1) We first create a lookup dataframe in which we have the number of vehicles for each incident, and then we use a left-join with the original dataframe `df`

```
df_n_of_veh = df.groupby(['Accident_Index']).apply(lambda x: sum(x['Casualty_Class'] == 'Driver')).to_frame(name='n_of_veh').reset_index()
df = df.merge(df_n_of_veh, how='left', on='Accident_Index')
```

---

2) This solution assumes that below each driver there are its passengers. Basically we increment by 1 each time we have `'Driver'` in `Casualty_Class` within each incident. Afterwards, since passengers or witnesses will still have 0's, we substitute them with 1's. This time we merge using the row indices, as they were ordered differently in `df_ref`

```
df_ref = df.groupby('Accident_Index').apply(lambda x: (x['Casualty_Class'] == 'Driver').astype(int).cumsum()).to_frame(name='reference').reset_index(level='Accident_Index').drop(['Accident_Index'], axis=1)
df_ref.loc[df_ref['reference'] == 0, 'reference'] = 1
df = df.merge(df_ref, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

---

**Output**
(sorry for the image, but I believe it was the shortest way to show it)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution. The point 2) doesn't work for cases when I have 3 drivers of 3 vehicles (without passengers) in an accident. Instead of giving reference as: 1, 2, 3 for each driver, it gave 1, 1, 2. :/

Comment: Really? I tried a case in which I have three drivers with three vehicles and `reference` gives me 1, 2, 3... Can you share the sample data with that specific accident?

Comment: I checked now and yes, with this sample dataset it works for all cases, but in my real dataset, it doesn't. I think it has something to do with the way strings were stored. I already had to use regex to change some strings via dictionary. I checked dtypes and it's all the same as in this sample dataset here. :/

Comment: So it still doesn't work? Could you add to `data` one specific case in which my code doesn't work? Maybe we can figure this out, but I still believe that my code should work if strings are stored correctly

Comment: There are special characters in original dataset that I translated to English, and there starts the problem. I will first try to solve that and then come back here. Your code works when the data is good. :)

Comment: Ok, keep me informed if you manage to clean your data! And afterwards please consider upvoting my answer if you found it helpful :)

Comment: I solved the character problem, and your code still doesn't work. The original data i am using is open data from this page: https://datos.madrid.es/egob/catalogo/300228-18-accidentes-trafico-detalle.csv You can try yourself

Comment: It's weird since it is working on the sample data, and the rationale seems correct.. What are the issues you are facing now?

Comment: Still the same thing, for me it also works on sample data. When I do the first part (counting the number of vehicles) on the original data, it counts it correctly, when I do the vehicle reference count on the original data, the counts are wrong. Can you please check the code with the original data? I will add the translation to the original post upper.

Comment: @mrn I've understood what the problem was. Basically pandas was ordering the rows differently than they were in the original dataframe, so in the joining step rows were assigned not correctly. We had to make the join specifying by row index (this is done using `left_index=True, right_index=True` in the `merge` function. I've uploaded my answer and tested it on the original data you posted, I believe now it works.

Comment: yes BINGO! Thank you so much for the help, I don't know how I skipped that step with indexes.

Comment: Finally we made it! Nice to hear that :)